# How to find Unit Tests that call a specific method during their execution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

Consider I have a Method `M()` which will be called during execution of Tests `T1()` and `T2()`.

Is there a way to find out that `M` will be executed in `T1` and `T2`?

I know that it would be impossible to find it out through the code. But using history of Unit Test's executions is good too.

Comment: Code coverage tools use these mechanisms. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Unit test frameworks often allow listening for whether a method is called. Nunit, Rhinomocks

Comment: @MrFox I'm using Nunit. But where can I find that?

Comment: mehrandvd @MrFox is referring to mocking frameworks such as RhinoMock, Moq, NSubstitute,... and they are commonly used with testing frameworks like NUnit and MSTest. They require you to use Dependancy Injection (Inversion of Control) and to call objects using interfaces through which these tools can Mock (or Stub) and verify interactions. Learning to write testable code will be a difficult but worthwhile journey. Try to concentrate on what you want the code to do and not how it does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) (also available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCover)) has this as a feature `-coverbytest`, the results of which can be visualized using [ReportGenerator](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator).

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan you're welcome - it's been a labor of love

Answer (score 1):

[NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net) is a great testing tool (paid) which shows test coverage (including in those methods) inline and in reporting (metrics).

[NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) (and others) allow you to do checks such as `.Recieved()` that allow you to specific both arguments expected and how many times you expected it to be called (or not called!)

http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/

```
[Test]
public void Should_execute_command_the_number_of_times_specified() {
  var command = Substitute.For<ICommand>();
  var repeater = new CommandRepeater(command, 3);
  //Act
  repeater.Execute();
  //Assert
  command.Received(3).Execute(); // << This will fail if 2 or 4 calls were received
}
```